# Is there any way to check user activation link has been sent

Tags: users

I have created user by profile-2 module with some certain roles,Initially user is in block state,there is one user manager that approved this user and send activation link by email.so how to check activation link already sent or not. if link already sent then need not send again.
For this Is there any module or custom code.
Please help me if anybody knows this.

Answer (score 1):

- Use **[Mail Logger](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger)**  module. It simply logs all outgoing emails into a database table.
- You can view the logged emails by going to the `Reports -> Outgoing` Mail log entries page.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but in this module we can clear log.If admin clear log then we miss the values.

Comment: That's why permissions are there. It requires a permission *access mail logger*. Just provide those permissions to users who want to clear the log